# how can i change "12 aug 2019"string to "2019-08-12" in golang?

Tags: json, datetime, go, backend

I have almost every type conversion and **time.format** module but still it given wrong output.

```
func main() {
    layout := "2019-01-23"
    str := "1938-19-02"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
'''

my input is "12 aug 2018" 
expected output is "2018-08-12"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a requirement to use the Jan 2, 2006 date when supplying the layout, and it's meant to tell the `time` package the layout of the date and/or time you want parsed.

```
func main() {
    layout := "2 Jan 2006"
    str := "12 aug 2018"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kn5zDXijw06